# Why cannot use brackets character in yacc/bison file?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

### source

ini.l

```
%option yylineno

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ini.tab.h"

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    printf("%d: %s at %s\n", yylineno, s, yytext);
}

#if defined YYDEBUG
extern int yydebug;
#endif

#define CASE_RETURN(token) do { case token: return #token; } while(0)

char *get_tokenname(token) {
    switch(token) {
        CASE_RETURN( IDENTIFIER     );
        CASE_RETURN( BRACKETS_LEFT  );
        CASE_RETURN( BRACKETS_RIGHT );
        CASE_RETURN( EQ             );
        default: return "Unknown";
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int token;
#if defined YYDEBUG
    yydebug = 1;
    while ((token = yylex()) != 0)
        printf("Token: %d/%-20s (%s)\n", token, get_tokenname(token), yytext);
#else
    yyparse();
#endif
    return 0;
}
%}

%%

[_a-zA-Z0-9]+           { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER; }
"["                     { return BRACKETS_LEFT; }
"]"                     { return BRACKETS_RIGHT; }
"="                     { return EQ; }
[ \t\r\n]               { }

%%
```

ini.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%union {
    char* str;    
}

%token <str> IDENTIFIER
%token BRACKETS_LEFT BRACKETS_RIGHT EQ

%%

input
    : /* empty */
    | input line
    | line
    ;

line
    : BRACKETS_LEFT section BRACKETS_RIGHT
    | key EQ value
    ;

section : IDENTIFIER { printf("section: %s\n" , $1); } ;
key     : IDENTIFIER { printf("key: %s, "     , $1); } ;
value   : IDENTIFIER { printf("value: %s\n"   , $1); } ;

%%
```

Makefile

```
CC              = gcc
LEX             = flex
YACC            = bison

TARGET          = a.out

LEX_SRC         = $(wildcard *.l)
YACC_SRC        = $(wildcard *.y)
SRC             = $(patsubst %.y,%.tab.c,$(YACC_SRC)) $(patsubst %.l,%.yy.c,$(LEX_SRC))
INC             = $(patsubst %.y,%.tab.h,$(YACC_SRC)) $(patsubst %.l,%.yy.h,$(LEX_SRC))

DEBUG           = -DYYDEBUG -DYYERROR_VERBOSE
LDFLAGS         = -L/usr/local/opt/bison/lib \
                -L/usr/local/opt/flex/lib \
                -I/usr/local/opt/flex/include

all: $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(TARGET)

debug: $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(TARGET) $(DEBUG)

.PRECIOUS: %.yy.c

%.yy.c: %.l
    $(LEX) -t $< > $@

.PRECIOUS: %.tab.c

%.tab.c:%.y
    $(YACC) -o $@ -d $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(SRC) $(INC) *.output
```

sample.ini

```
[foobar]
foo=bar
```

### test

```
$ make clean && make
$ ./a.out < sample.ini
section: foobar
key: foo, value: bar
```

Everything looks fine

```
$ make clean && make debug
$ ./a.out < sample.ini
Token: 259/BRACKETS_LEFT        ([)
Token: 258/IDENTIFIER           (foobar)
Token: 260/BRACKETS_RIGHT       (])
Token: 258/IDENTIFIER           (foo)
Token: 261/EQ                   (=)
Token: 258/IDENTIFIER           (bar)
```

Then i changed `BRACKETS_LEFT` to `'['`

```
$ git diff -U0
diff --git a/ini.l b/ini.l
index 2538353..12b2524 100644
--- a/ini.l
+++ b/ini.l
@@ -24 +23,0 @@ char *get_tokenname(token) {
-        CASE_RETURN( BRACKETS_LEFT  );
@@ -47 +45,0 @@ int main(void) {
-"["                     { return BRACKETS_LEFT; }
diff --git a/ini.y b/ini.y
index c605ea4..1498ff5 100644
--- a/ini.y
+++ b/ini.y
@@ -11 +11 @@
-%token BRACKETS_LEFT BRACKETS_RIGHT EQ
+%token BRACKETS_RIGHT EQ
@@ -22 +22 @@ line
-    : BRACKETS_LEFT section BRACKETS_RIGHT
+    : '[' section BRACKETS_RIGHT
```

The bison give me an error

```
$ make clean && make debug
$ ./a.out < sample.ini
1: syntax error at [

$ make clean && make debug
$ ./a.out < sample.ini
[Token: 258/IDENTIFIER           (foobar)
Token: 259/BRACKETS_RIGHT       (])
Token: 258/IDENTIFIER           (foo)
Token: 260/EQ                   (=)
Token: 258/IDENTIFIER           (bar)
```

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bison to be able to use a character token like '[', the scanner must return precisely '['.

Your scanner doesn't seem to return anything for unknown characters. You need to add a default rule:

```
.    { return yytext[0]; }
```

I recommend always using the flex `nodefault` option to catch such errors. Also, the `-Wall` option for gcc when you compile. And check the documentation for flex and bison to see how to use their debugging traces, rather than building your own. The built-in debugging is easy to use and produces reasonably complete output.

Comment: That didn't explain the syntax error. For instance, it does not appear if one compiles the two files separately.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Look right at the end of the question, you can see the transcripts. The syntax error is produced by OP's parser (running `./a.out`). Then OP runs with their trace feature enabled, and you can see that the scanner never produces the `[` token. You can even see the `ECHO` of the `[` from the default lex rule, at the beginning of the debug output.